# Angular dependency injection fail from basecomponent when a comment is added

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, dependency-injection

When extending a base class, if the main component has a comment right after the component declaration, the base class does not properly inject the dependency.  I ran into this issue in a main project of mine last night, and was able to reproduce it with these steps:

1. Using VS Code, create a new angular project (I used `ng new test-app --routing`)
2. Create "appComponentBase.component.ts" (code below)
3. Create "test.service.ts" (code below)

test.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })
  export class TestService {

    public serviceMessage =  "I'm here!";

    constructor()
    {
    }
  }
```

appComponentBase.component.ts

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from "@angular/core";
import { TestService } from "./test.service";
@Component({
    selector: 'AppComponentBase',
    template: ``,
})

export class AppComponentBase {


    constructor(testService: TestService)
    {
        console.log(testService.serviceMessage);
    }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponentBase } from './appComponentBase.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent extends AppComponentBase {
  /* Declarations */

  title = 'test-app';
}
```

These are the only changes I made to the generated test app.

When I run this (`npm start`), i get "cannot read property 'serviceMessage' of undefined."  This is because with this code setup, TestService is not properly getting injected.

When I remove the /* Declarations */ comment, this error does not occur.

I was not able to reproduce this on stackblitz, I believe they might be pre-processing some of the code going in.

Can anyone tell me why that comment would block dependency injection from a base class?

Comment: Well, that's strange indeed. What happens if you leave the comment where it is but put a constructor underneath `title`, that calls `super()`?

Comment: That works. As does a constructor without a base class.  I can also move the comment so that there's no line break between it and title (so on the line above, but no space) and it works.  I'm guessing this is some weird preprocessing, but very strange.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. 

Comment: I just made it and work. is `*/Declarations*/`as you put in question or `/*Declarations*/`as you show in code (the `*/` vs `/*`)?. My data: angular-devkit/core: 11.0.7, angular-cli: 11.0.7, rxjs 6.6.7, typescript 4.0.7 :(

Comment: As it is in the code. Can you provide an answer with your exact code copied over for that component?

Comment: I think it's worth issuing a bug in the Angular GitHub repo. Seems to me like an issue with either TypeScript compiler or how Angular translates it's needs. Perhaps the comment affects how the AST is created

Comment: Another thing to try - install latest angular packages version. Perhaps the bug you are facing was fixed long ago

Answer (score 1):

Well your `basecomponent` requires `TestService` in the constructor. You are not providing it.

This:

```
export class AppComponent extends AppComponentBase {
    title = 'test-app';
}
```

Is almost equal to this:

```
export class AppComponent extends AppComponentBase {
    title = 'test-app';
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
}
```

And that clearly is not going to work. This will however:

```
export class AppComponent extends AppComponentBase {
    title = 'test-app';
    constructor(testService: TestService){
        super(testService);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The explanation above is not completely right. In typescript constructors are passed down.

```
class A{
    constructor(val: string){
        console.log(val);
    }
}

class B extends A{

}

const a: A = new B('as');
```

However, the angular DI framework requires you to explicitly state the dependencies. So from a typescript/javascript point of view, the code is valid. Though, angular has some problems with it.

[Docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#inject-into-a-derived-class)

> Take care when writing a component that inherits from another component. If the base component has injected dependencies, you must re-provide and re-inject them in the derived class and then pass them down to the base class through the constructor.

Comment: The base component has its own constructor, and is therefore providing TestService itself.  It is not a requirement that I'm aware of that the parent component has to supply the dependency injection to a base class

Comment: That is just how inheritance works. Wheter it is java, c# or typescript. That fact that is dependency injection doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Ok...have you tried recreating this?  I'm skeptical to believe your "this is how inheritance works" bit because i can use my dependency injected object in my app component without specifying a constructor in my app component.

Comment: I can confirm, @RobinDijkhof is right, you have to supply the service

Comment: I will also agree (and give the bounty to Robin) on this, because I'm reading Angular.IO inheritance and it is saying the exact same thing.  BUT -- why does is it working in the first place then?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ervgog Here is a stackblitz link of it working without passing the service from component to base

Comment: @RobinDijkhof i disagree on "equality" of these. When you do not provide the constructor to the derived class it implicitly has the constructor of a base class. Thus DI is working. Apparently there is some issue with the codegen as adding a comment breaks the implicit injection

Comment: @Sergey that is exactly what i am saying in my edit.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  Between your answer, Angular.io research, and generally agreeing that this "shouldn't" happen, I think the conclusion I've come to is that angular is a little more strict than typescript in this sense, and *something* in the background is causing an issue here.  Given that angular explicitly states that the component has to provide parameters to its base, i think that is enough for me.  Of course I would still like to know the behind the scenes/guts of what it actually thinks its doing, but this will do.  Thanks everyone!